# Send email through local SMTP vs google app engine

Tags: email, smtp, google, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

My web site is supposed to send email to customers and its hosted on a VPS. Should I use local SMTP or is it better to use a third party SMTP provider like Google App Engine?

What are the disadvantages and advantages for each method (Spam, reliability and so on...)

Comment: AppEngine does not have SMTP services. You might mean Google Apps?

Comment: i followed this link:http://code.google.com/intl/iw-IL/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html

Comment: So were you thinking of sending a request from your VPS -> AppEngine -> send mail?

Comment: yes. or use my own SMTP.

Comment: Would you really want to manage your own SMTP server? Getting email into inboxes is not a science, there's a lot of gobbledegook that third-party SMTP providers handle so you don't have to.

Comment: what are the alternatives? i'M lookign for the disadvantages and advantages for each method

Answer (score 4):

Unless the IP your VPS is sitting on has been blacklisted from a previous user, or your ISP is just plain evil, you should be fine sending out emails from a local SMTP server.

For maximum deliverability you will want to look at:

- Ensuring you have setup your SMTP server NOT to rely mail, and is safely behind a firewall. (this is a surefire way to get blacklisted within days)
- Ensure you have reverse-DNS setup for your VPS and that the host name your SMTP server is using matches your domain
- Adding [SPF records](http://www.openspf.org/) for your domain.
- Checkout [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org/) if possible.

Your AppEngine approach seems convoluted, if you wanted to use a third party system something like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: great answer! do i have any way to know that i'm blacklisted? if i'm on vps aren't i'm automaticly behind FW?why reverse DNS setup and how do i do that?

Comment: Your VPS company (or whoever you use for DNS) will probably have some way of setting up reverse-DNS for your mail-server. It's needed as some servers will check that you are not just making up a domain/mailserver to send mail from.

Comment: Firewall will depend on how you setup your VPS. Who do you use?

Comment: i'm looking right now for a VPS provider in the US.i'm thinking of accuwebhosting.

Comment: you can see your blacklist status at http://www.mxtoolbox.com

Answer (score 0):

If you have less then 500 mails/day I would use Google apps (free!), this way you know 100% that all is working fine. Plus, no need to setup your own mail server.

For paid google apps, the limit is 2000 mails/day.